# Get x coordinate of a component

Tags: java, location, jcombobox

How can I get the `x` axis location from a `JComboBox`? I want only the `x`, not the `x,y`

```
Point x;
System.out.println(tablebox.getLocation(x));
```

Doesn't work. It gives me `x,y`.

Comment: Use [`getX()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getX()) on the component itself.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Are you kidding me?? I didn't even see that!! Thank you!

Comment: Actually I'm kidding. This won't work. (I'm kidding, it will work).. etc..